# Could anyone tell me what the error is in this code? I want to get the info of the list in a dataframe but I got it empty

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

To get the info (info2) from the API:

```
ServiceTypes = ["Regular", "Night"]
url = 'https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/Route?serviceTypes='
tag = '&app_key=%2068180443ed4baffb6640824d8aa7db5c&app_id=2f7e332e'

info2 = []

for service in ServiceTypes:
    r = rq.get(url + str(service) + tag)
    time.sleep(2)
    info2.append(json.loads(r.content))
info2
```

This is a sample of the results from the API (info2):

```
[[{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Line, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities',
   'id': '1',
   'name': '1',
   'modeName': 'bus',
   'disruptions': [],
   'created': '2019-08-20T16:25:25.377Z',
   'modified': '2019-08-20T16:25:25.377Z',
   'lineStatuses': [],
   'routeSections': [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.MatchedRoute, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities',
     'name': 'New Oxford Street - Canada Water Bus Station',
     'direction': 'outbound',
     'originationName': 'New Oxford Street',
     'destinationName': 'Canada Water Bus Station',
     'originator': '490000235Z',
     'destination': '490004733D',
     'serviceType': 'Regular',
     'validTo': '2019-12-23T00:00:00Z',
     'validFrom': '2019-08-17T00:00:00Z'},
    {'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.MatchedRoute, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities',
     'name': 'Canada Water Bus Station - Tottenham Court Road',
     'direction': 'inbound',
     'originationName': 'Canada Water Bus Station',
     'destinationName': 'Tottenham Court Road',
     'originator': '490004733C',
     'destination': '490000235N',
     'serviceType': 'Regular',
     'validTo': '2019-12-23T00:00:00Z',
     'validFrom': '2019-08-17T00:00:00Z'}],
   'serviceTypes': [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineServiceTypeInfo, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities',
     'name': 'Regular',
     'uri': '/Line/Route?ids=1&serviceTypes=Regular'}],
   'crowding': {'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Crowding, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities'}},
```

And I am trying to get in a dataframe the values with this code:

```
info2 = np.squeeze(info2).tolist()
dftypes = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["id", "name", "modeName", "routeSections"])
dfroutes = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["name","direction","originationName","destinationName","serviceType"])
i=0
j=0
for dic in info2:
    for key in dic:
        if key in dftypes.columns.tolist():
            dftypes.loc[i,key]=str(dic[key])

        if key == 'routeSections':
            for dic2 in dic[key]:
                    for key2 in dic2:
                        if key2 in dfroutes.columns.tolist():
                            dfroutes.loc[j,key2]=str(dic2[key2])
                    j+=1
    i+=1

dfroutes
```

But I got an empty dataframe:

name    direction   originationName destinationName serviceType

Could you please show me the error? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be interested in [pd.io.json.json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html). It will unnest routeSections for you. Look at this small example and the fact we don't need to use any loops.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

def retrieve_dataframe(service_type):

    url = 'https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/Route?serviceTypes='
    tag = '&app_key=%2068180443ed4baffb6640824d8aa7db5c&app_id=2f7e332e'

    r = requests.get(url + service_type + tag)
    data = r.json() # .json() will convert your request.content to json

    # meta_prefix = '_' as there is a name conflict 
    # (the record_path and meta has a variable called 'name')
    return pd.io.json.json_normalize(
        data=data, 
        record_path='routeSections', 
        meta=['id', 'name', 'modeName'], 
        meta_prefix='_'
    )

service_types = ["Regular", "Night"]
df = pd.concat(retrieve_dataframe(x).assign(service_type=x) for x in service_types)

# Print first and last 2 rows
print(pd.concat((df.head(2),df.tail(2))))
```

Returns

```
                                            $type  \
0   Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.MatchedRoute, Tf...   
1   Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.MatchedRoute, Tf...   
13  Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.MatchedRoute, Tf...   
14  Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.MatchedRoute, Tf...   

                                                 name direction  \
0        New Oxford Street - Canada Water Bus Station  outbound   
1     Canada Water Bus Station - Tottenham Court Road   inbound   
13  Walthamstow Central Underground Station - Brix...   inbound   
14  Brixton Underground Station - Walthamstow Cent...  outbound   

                            originationName  \
0                         New Oxford Street   
1                  Canada Water Bus Station   
13  Walthamstow Central Underground Station   
14              Brixton Underground Station   

                            destinationName   originator  destination  \
0                  Canada Water Bus Station   490000235Z   490004733D   
1                      Tottenham Court Road   490004733C   490000235N   
13              Brixton Underground Station  940GZZLUWWL  940GZZLUBXN   
14  Walthamstow Central Underground Station  940GZZLUBXN  940GZZLUWWL   

   serviceType               validTo             validFrom       _id  \
0      Regular  2019-12-23T00:00:00Z  2019-08-17T00:00:00Z         1   
1      Regular  2019-12-23T00:00:00Z  2019-08-17T00:00:00Z         1   
13       Night  2500-12-24T00:00:00Z  2015-03-08T00:00:00Z  victoria   
14       Night  2500-12-24T00:00:00Z  2015-03-08T00:00:00Z  victoria   

       _name _modeName service_type  
0          1       bus      Regular  
1          1       bus      Regular  
13  Victoria      tube        Night
```

Comment: Thanks @Anton vBR, your code works but my problem is that I need to loop the list: r = rq.get(url + str(service) + tag), where service is Regular and Night, could you show me the right direction to get the info of both, Regular and Night? This is why I was executing a "for" in the previous code.

Comment: @Alexa how about now? By using `assign()` we add another column to the frame called service_type which holds the service_type.

Comment: Thank you very much @Anton vBR your answer really helped me!!

Answer (score 1):

some changes in the last part of your code:-

```
    for k1 in dic:
        for key in k1.keys():
            if key in dftypes.columns.tolist():
                dftypes.loc[i,key]=str(k1[key])

            if key == 'routeSections':
                for dic2 in k1[key]:
                        for key2 in dic2:
                            if key2 in dfroutes.columns.tolist():
                                dfroutes.loc[j,key2]=str(dic2[key2])
                        j+=1
    i+=1

dfroutes
```

I hope it helps.